# SessionStorage + jQuery: Iterating over all existing keys with name like (wildcard)

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

I use SessionStorage to store information about selected items to pack.
So I have a number of keys like (pack01, pack02, pack07, pack22, etc), but there are also other keys in the SessionStorage too.

I would like to write a function to iterate through all keys that the name starts with (pack) - only these ones.

Sample objects in SessionStorage:

```
pack01: [{"pack_items":1,"pack_name":"testname1"}] 
pack02: [{"pack_items":2,"pack_name":"testname2"}] 
test: test
```

Code so far:

```
for (let i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
      const key = sessionStorage.key(i);
      if(sessionStorage[key].hasOwnProperty('pack_items')){
          console.log(sessionStorage[key]['pack_items']);
      }
      else {
        console.log('FALSE');
      }
      console.log(`${key}: ${sessionStorage.getItem(key)}`);
}
```

Any advice? Thank you

Comment: _"I would like to write a function to iterate through all keys that the name starts with (pack) - only these ones."_ - What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? `sessionStorage` is just another object, so all the methods/functions/loops for objects also work with `sessionStorage`. There's also a [`.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/length) property, and a [`.key()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/key) method that accepts a number.

Comment: @Andreas I updated the question. I tried to go with "hasOwnProperty", but that doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: Why not have this in Session Storage instead? "packs: [ { ...pack1info }, { ...pack2info }]".

Comment: _"iterate through all keys that the name starts with..."_ - Nothing in your script checks a key.